# How to find the size of the effect of an independent numeric variable on a dependent ordinal variable?

Tags: r, regression, anova

I have a sample dataset like:

```
name<-c("Bob","JACK","Steve","Daniel","Ed")
ans1<-c("5","4","4","1","4")
hours<-c(200,100,150,10,500)
datat<-data.frame(name,ans1,hours)
```

As you can see in this dataset there are 5 students and their answers to a confidence test in a scale from 1 to 5 after having spent certain amount of hours preparing themselves. The question of this confidence test is: How ready do you feel for the exams (from 1 to 5) after having read certain amount of hours?" I am not sure what kind of analysis should I perform in R on this dataframe  What model would make sense? 1-WAY ANOVA seems the best fit to me as I want to find how the studying hours affect the answer of every student.Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your outcome variable is ordinal, an *ordinal logistic regression model* would be appropriate.  There are several types of such models, so you would need to identify the one appropriate for your setting since each model has a different interpretation.

See the article available at http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0102-311X2008001600010 for a list of different types of ordinal logistic regression models, which includes:

- Proportional odds model;
- Partial proportional odds model.

Also, see https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/ on how you can implement the *proportional odds model* in R.

Are these 5 students the only students you have data for? I don't know whether you can fit an ordinal logistic regression model reliably when you have data from only 5 students.  If you can (i.e., if your model fit doesn't explode), expect to see large standard errors and wide confidence intervals coming out from your model, reflecting the limited amount of information available in the data from only 5 students.

A one-way ANOVA model will not work since it would require your outcome variable to be continuous, which it is not.  An example of continuous variable is body weight (which can take any value - in principle - within a range of biologically plausible values).  Having said that, there are people out there who would treat the ordinal outcome variable "as if" it were continuous and analyze it using one-way ANOVA.

Comment:

I thought you were going to treat the confidence score on a specific question as the outcome and the hours as the predictor? The students prepare first and then take the test.

If you use the clm() function in the ordinal package to implement the *proportional odds model* (aka cumulative logit model) relating the outcome ans1 to the predictor hours, your model for the confidence score on the first question would be:

```
install.packages("ordinal")
require(ordinal)

model1 <- clm(ans1 ~ hours, data = datat) 

model1

summary(model1)
```

For the above code to work, you would have to convert ans1 to an ordinal factor first.  Try something like this for the conversion:

```
datat$ans1 <- factor(datat$ans1, 
                     levels=c("1","2","3","4","5"),
                     ordinal=TRUE)
```

and then run the code suggested above.

See Section 2 of the document ftp://ftp.stat.math.ethz.ch/R-CRAN/web/packages/ordinal/vignettes/clm_tutorial.pdf for details on how to interpret the resulting model).

Comment: The students are 60. Thanks for your time. Would it make sense to transform the hours into a factor as well? For example 0-20 hours would be " basic",20-40"  would be medium and  so on. What kind of analysis could I use then?

Comment: Ok, great!  If you have 60 students, you should be fine fitting the model. If you keep Time as is (not a factor), then you can easily see if longer preparation times are associated with higher confidence scores.  If you convert it into a factor, you run into the issue of using subjective cut-offs to define each time category and also losing information.  But you would still use ordinal logistic regression, regardless of whether you treat time as continuous/discrete or ordinal.

Comment: Thanks the subjective selection is an issue but probably I could get rid off outliers by using this for example 30000 hours or something. As I can understand from ordinal log reg I could run the model not only for one questionnaire(hours~ans1) but for more at the same time hours~ans1+ans2+ans3. Would that make sense or should I run it for each questionaire separatetdly? The other questionnaires are of the same logic approximatelly and answered by the same students.

Comment: @firmo23: Please see the comment I added at the bottom of my original answer.

Comment: You cover my thoughts thanks. Suppose that we have 3 questionnaires intead of one. Would it make sense (if they measure approximatelly the same thing) to find the average of them and convert our outcome variable to numeric? Which would be the best method in that case?

Comment: I am a firm believer in research questions - they really guide our statistical analyses. What is your research question? Are you trying to find out if longer preparation times are associated with  (1) higher average confidence scores across 3 similar questionnaires or (2) higher confidence scores on a specific questionnaire? The answer may depend on how the questionnaires are used in practice: together or separately. If together, perhaps (1) makes sense. Otherwise, (2) makes sense.  The research question should be specified prior to collecting and seeing the data.